# Using the PS command in the variables SaltStack

Tags: powershell, salt-stack

I have a State, which should give me an output if the folder exists or not.
I don't know how to escape the name of the folder Programs files so PS knows what I mean.

```
{% set label = salt['cmd.run']('powershell.exe "test-path \"$env:SystemDrive\\Program Files (x86)\\Folder\""') %}

{% if label == 'True' %}
  First:
    cmd.run:
      - name: Write-Host "Exist"
      - shell: powershell

{% else %}
  Secondary:
    cmd.run:
      - name: Write-Host " NOT "
      - shell: powershell
{% endif %}
```

I get NOT each time I try, but the folder exists

Can you tell me how to make this work. And where can I find information on how to escape lines in YAML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using the Saltstack [file module](https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.file.html) to check existence of a directory with the `directory_exists` function.

This allows us to use the [requisite system](https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/ref/states/requisites.html) to trigger further states.

Example:

```yaml
check-dir-exists:
  module.run:
    - name: file.directory_exists
    - path: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\SomeDirectory'

show-dir-exists:
  cmd.run:
    - name: Write-Host "Dir exists"
    - shell: powershell
    - require:
        - module: check-dir-exists

show-dir-not-exist:
  cmd.run:
    - name: Write-Host "Dir not exists"
    - shell: powershell
    - onfail:
        - module: check-dir-exists
```

Or store the return value `True/False` in a variable and match condition in `if/else` statement.

Example:

```yaml
{% set label = salt['file.directory_exists']('C:\Program Files (x86)\SomeDirectory') %}

{% if label %}
show-dir-exists:
  cmd.run:
    - name: Write-Host "Dir exists"
    - shell: powershell
{% else %}
show-dir-not-exist:
  cmd.run:
    - name: Write-Host "Dir not exists"
    - shell: powershell
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem most likely isn't in the call to powershell.exe, because this is what I get when I run the following from the cmd.exe command prompt:

```
C:\>powershell.exe "test-path \"$env:SystemDrive\\Program Files (x86)\\DoesntExist\""
False

C:\>powershell.exe "test-path \"$env:SystemDrive\\Program Files (x86)\\""
True
```